# How to turn this code into list comprehension format?

Tags: python

```
names = []
for batch in node_batch:
    if 'name' not in batch:
        name = ''
    else:
        name = batch['name']
    names.append(name)
```

I want to use one line like the following to create the names list:

```
names = [batch['name'] for batch in node_batch]
```

Is that possible?

Comment: List comprehensions aren't a "format" for loops. They're different things.

Comment: Post some sample data, and expected result.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an if expression.

```py
names = [batch['name'] if 'name' in batch else '' for batch in node_batch]
```

The [`dict.get`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html) method is more appropriate for this case, for which a default value can be specified as the second argument (as suggested by [flakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280538)).

```py
names = [batch.get('name', '') for batch in node_batch]
```

Comment: I would do: `[batch.get('name', '') for batch in node_batch]`

Comment: What about just using names = [batch['name'] if 'name' in batch else ''?

Comment: @marlon You still need `for batch in node_batch` to complete the comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in functionality of a Dictionary instead of `if-else` block.

```
[batch.get('name', '') for batch in node_batch]
```

If there is no `name` key found in `batch` then return empty string.